# How can I develop a script with frida to intercept when it's encrypted?

Tags: javascript, reverse-engineering, frida

I have a problem where I can't develop Scripts for frida with javascript, I would like a base to intercept the function in which it returns anything from a class com.example.utils:

```
`public class utils {
    public static String error;

    public static void onCreate() {
        GetError();
    }

    public static Activity getActivity() {
        return UnityPlayer.currentActivity;
    }

    public static void print(String str) {
        if (Functions.isDebug) {
            Log.i(AdColonyAppOptions.UNITY, str);
        }
    }

    public static void GetError() {
        StackTraceElement[] stackTrace;
        try {
            throw new Exception();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            error = String.valueOf(error) + e.getMessage();
            for (StackTraceElement stackTraceElement : e.getStackTrace()) {
                error = String.valueOf(error) + stackTraceElement.getClassName() + "->" + stackTraceElement.getMethodName() + "\n";
            }
            print(error);
        }
    }

    public static boolean isDebuggable() {
        return (getActivity().getApplicationContext().getApplicationInfo().flags & 2) != 0 || Debug.isDebuggerConnected();
    }

    public static String XOR(String str, String str2, boolean z) {
        if (z) {
            try {
                return Base64.encodeToString(EncryptDecrypt(str.getBytes(C.UTF8_NAME), str2.getBytes(C.UTF8_NAME)), 0);
            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException unused) {
                return "";
            }
        }
        try {
            return new String(EncryptDecrypt(Base64.decode(str, 0), str2.getBytes(C.UTF8_NAME)), C.UTF8_NAME);
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException unused2) {
            return "";
        }
    }

    private static byte[] EncryptDecrypt(byte[] bArr, byte[] bArr2) {
        int length = bArr2.length;
        int length2 = bArr.length;
        byte[] bArr3 = new byte[256];
        for (int i = 0; i < 256; i++) {
            bArr3[i] = (byte) i;
        }
        int i2 = 0;
        for (int i3 = 0; i3 < 256; i3++) {
            i2 = (((i2 + bArr3[i3]) + bArr2[i3 % length]) % 256) & 255;
            byte b = bArr3[i3];
            bArr3[i3] = bArr3[i2];
            bArr3[i2] = b;
        }
        int i4 = 0;
        int i5 = 0;
        for (int i6 = 0; i6 < length2; i6++) {
            i4 = ((i4 + 1) % 256) & 255;
            i5 = ((i5 + bArr3[i4]) % 256) & 255;
            byte b2 = bArr3[i4];
            bArr3[i4] = bArr3[i5];
            bArr3[i5] = b2;
            bArr[i6] = (byte) (bArr3[((bArr3[i4] + bArr3[i5]) % 256) & 255] ^ bArr[i6]);
        }
        return bArr;
    }
}
```

How can I develop a script with frida to intercept when it's encrypted?

I tried to write codes but it always went wrong, please help me

Comment: Is the code from an Android app?

Answer (score 0):

The following script should intercept the `EncryptDecrypt` method of the code you have posted and print the return value as hex encoded string:

```
Java.perform(() => {
    let testClass = Java.use('com.example.utils');
    let methodToHook = testClass.EncryptDecrypt.overload('[B', '[B');
    methodToHook.implementation = function (arg1, arg2) {
        console.log('EncryptDecrypt called');
        console.log('EncryptDecrypt arg1 = ' + encodeHex(arg1));
        console.log('EncryptDecrypt arg2 = ' + encodeHex(arg2));
        let retVal = methodToHook.call(testClass, arg1, arg2);
        console.log(encodeHex(retVal)); 
    };

    function encodeHex(byteArray) {
        const HexClass = Java.use('org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Hex');
        const StringClass = Java.use('java.lang.String');
        const hexChars = HexClass.encodeHex(byteArray);
        return StringClass.$new(hexChars).toString();
    }
});
```

The `encodeHex` function is necessary as in Java calling `toString()` of a `byte[]` does not print the content, but just the internal object reference - and I assume the content of the byte array is what you want to view. `encodeHex` will only work if you are on Android or the Java application you hook includes Apache commons codec library.

If you don't know how to hook a method you can use a short-curt: Load the APK in [jadx-gui](https://github.com/skylot/jadx/), select the method you want to hook and select `Copy as frida snippet` from the context menu. This will generate a short JavaScript snippet you can copy into your Frida script.